# How do I scrape the contents of links I scraped from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a websites search results page with beautiful soup, the website is built in such a way that you search for something, you have a result page then you click on each result to go to the products page with full details of the product. The information I want to scrape is not on the result search page so I need to navigate through each search results product page to scrape it. How best can I perform this? I know how to scrape the search results page but the information I need is not there. Please help.

Comment: do you know how to get all the links from that page?

Comment: You are having too less information to process this. You know the method just search for tools like selenium and beautiful soup that will do it. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask better question.